# Under what conditions is the mixture of two normal distributions bimodal?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm interested in characterizing the conditions under which the mixture distribution resulting from two normal distributions is bimodal.

Let's say we have a function $f(x)$ defined as the sum of two normal distributions: one standard normal X1 ~ $ N(0, 1)$ and one general normal X2 ~ $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. WLOG let's assume $\mu > 0 $. We are interested in the function:

$f(x) = \alpha N(0, 1) + (1-\alpha)N(\mu, \sigma^2)$

I am interested in finding the conditions on $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ under which $f(x)$ is bimodal, meaning it has two distinct local maxima with a local minimum in between.

For instance, if we fix $\alpha = 1/2$ and $\sigma^2 = 1$ and vary $\mu$ we find that $f$ is bimodal when $\mu > 2$. For this special (symmetric) case, we can verify this by calculating that the second derivative at the critical point $f'(\mu/2)$ is negative iff $\mu > 2$ (for $\mu = 2$, we don't have bimodal $f$). But this approach won't work if we vary $\sigma^2$.

Fixing $\alpha = 0.5$, I obtained through simulation (with the assumption - informed by the behavior of the the derivative of the normal distribution - that, if $f$ were to be bimodal, the peaks would lie in the interval $(0, \mu)$, with one peak on either side $\mu / 2$) the following graph, which seems to indicate a sort of logarithmic relationship between $\sigma^2$ and $\mu^*$, the value of $\mu$ (as a function of $\sigma$) at which $f$ becomes bimodal.  However, note that my approach to making this is a bit finicky and that potentially some of the estimates for certain pairs of parameters, especially near the boundary, may be incorrect:

[image]

In an attempt to solve the problem more generally, I looked at the first and second derivatives of f, but got very messy expressions that neither I nor my computer (with sympy) could solve analytically. My idea was to try and characterize when $f'(x) = 0$ has 3 real solutions instead of 1, but I'm not really sure how to approach the problem beyond that.

I am seeking an inequality relating $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $\alpha$ (or feel free to fix $\alpha = 0.5$ if that makes the problem significantly easier) that specifies conditions under which $f(x)$ is bimodal. Specifying $\mu^*$ as a function of $\sigma$ and $\alpha$ would be ideal (assuming bimodality is monotonic in $\mu$ given $\sigma$ and $\alpha$)

EDIT: It seems likely that for large and small enough values of $\sigma^2$ that this condition is equivalent to the joint conditions $f(0) > f(\mu/2)$ and $f(\mu) > f(\mu/2)$ . Perhaps there is a similar, if slightly more nuanced, kind of relation we can exploit for values of $\sigma^2$ closer to 1, using some properties of the normal distribution and its derivatives? The "advantage" we might have when X2 has variance closer to 1 is that the local minimum should be "pushed" closer to u/2.

Comment: You are talking about a mixture distribution but do not use the word

Comment: Thanks, I edited the title and intro to include that term.

Comment: Suppose there are a lot of dogs near your house and, comparatively a lot of cats where you work. The distribution of dogs would be right-skewed/negatively skewed and the distribution of cats would be left-skewed/positively skewed* if you plot them against distance from your house. Add the two distributions together and the number of "animals" or *pets, cats/dogs, will have bimodal distribution.

Comment: EDIT: It seems plausible that for large and small enough values of 2 that this condition is equivalent to the joint conditions (0)>(/2) and ()>(/2). Perhaps there is a similar, if slightly more nuanced, kind of relation we can exploit for values of 2 closer to 1, using some properties of the normal distribution and its derivatives? The "advantage" we have when X2 has variance closer to 1 is that the local minimum should be "pushed" closer to u/2.

Comment: Just playing: Your suggested $f(0)>f(\mu/2)$ and $f(\mu)>f(\mu/2)$ test would fail for $\alpha=\frac14$, $\mu=3.4$, $\sigma^2=3$, as it has two peaks but $f(0)$ is lower than any other value in $[0,\mu]$ so risks not spotting the local minimum.  This may make things slower